# LoggingSession/LoggingChannel (Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics)

Tags: c#, logging, debug-diagnostic-tool

I use the [Microsoft Logging Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Logging) to generate an `ETL` file. This API is great for logging... except that i can't figure a way to read these logs !

Using WPA, ETViewer... I can see the events but not the log messages.

Maybe I have to load some `PDB` file for WPA or ETViewer. But the first one just doesn't let me do it, and the second just said that "no provider is found in the PDB file."

Did anyone have success reading the `ETL` files generated by this sample/API(`Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics`) with any trace viewer (real time or not) ?

Answer (score 1):

I use [PerfView](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567)

Browse to your ETL file, expand it, then double click on the Events item inside.

[image: PerfView]

Comment: Great ! Exactly what i was looking for. Any tip for view/filter events by criticity ? (verbose, info, warning, critic, etc...)

Comment: I believe you can filter the events in the "Events" window at the top.  I'm away from my desk so I can't tell for sure.  If you're more interested in working with the data, there is a tool called "Tracerpt" (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490959.aspx) that allows you to export the events as an XML file.  You can put all of your ETLs in a folder and do a little PowerShell to export and manipulate all of the events as you see fit.

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-136 at a 53:45 he uses the tool.  This video is excellent btw.  Definitely worth the watch

Comment: Actually https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732700.aspx is a better ref for tracerpt